# Python 3 64-bit, connect to 32odbc connection?

Tags: python, anaconda, pyodbc

I want to use spyder console and use odbc connection to get some data. 
However I only have the odbc available in 32 bit.

Is there anyway to connect to odbc32 via python 3 64 bit? Upgrading the odbc to 64 bit is not possible.

I currently use pyodbc to connect, ever since I went to spyder 64 bit this doesnt work.

```
con = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN='+'Stack',autocommit=True)
```

Error:

```
Error: ('IM014', '[IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to connect to odbc32 via python 3 64 bit?

No.